A group with exactly half of the elements in one conjugacy class
Suppose $G$ is a finite group and there exists a conjugacy class $S$ in $G$ contains exactly $|G|/2$ many elements. What can we say about $G$? For example if $G$ is a Dihedral group $D_{n}$ with $n$ an odd integer then all reflections in $D_{n}$ are in the same class.
To be more general. Let $A$ be a finite Abelian group with odd order. Then, the group $G=A\rtimes(\mathbb Z/2)$, where $\varphi:x\mapsto -x$ is the nontrivial automorphism of order $2$, also satisfies our condition.
An easy observation is that for any $g\in S$ we have the centralizer $|C_G(g)|=2$. So $C_G(g)=\{e,g\}$ in this case, which implies $g^2=e$. Now the conjugacy action $G$ on $S$ gives an injective map $i:G\to S_{|G|/2}$. The image $i(g)$ for $g\in G$ has either $0,1$ or $|G|/2$ fixed points($g\not\in S\cup\{e\},g\in S,g=e$).
Since $i(g)$ is of order $2$ and has a unique fixed point for $g\in S$. So it is a product of $2$-cycles in $S_{|G|/2}$. This implies that $|G|/2$ is a odd number.
Now I have no idea how to proceed.

The even permutations in $S_n$ would be such a conjugacy class, would it not? Also, I always take an opportunity to try to root out the abomination that is the $D_{2n}$ convention for dihedral groups. It acts naturally on $n$ elements and is a subgroup of $S_n$ (at least for $n\geq3$). "But it has $2n$ elements" is irrelevant,  that's not how we name $S_n$ or $A_n$, so it shouldn't be how we name $D_n$.

@Arthur The conjugacy classes in $S_n$ is determined by its cycle structure. So all even permutations does not form a conjugacy class. Also thanks for your comment on dihedral groups!

@cybat Of course, you're right, I'm mixing concepts here. And I'm exaggerating a little about the $D_{2n}$ notation. The thing that's actually bad is that there are two competing  conventions in active use. I'm having a bit of fun as I do my tiny part in trying to consolidate all mathematicians to a single side.

Since $Z(G)=\cap_{x \in G} C_G(x)$ you see that either $Z(G)=1$, or $Z(G)={1,g}$, in which case $#Cl_G(g)=1$, whence $|G|=2$.

Another observation: for all $g \in S$ we have $gS = G\setminus S$. Because of cardinality observations, this is equivalent to $gS \cap S =\emptyset$. Suppose by contradiction that there exists $h \in S$ such that $gh \in S$. Since any element in $S$ squares to the identity, we have $ghgh =e$. Multiplying by $g,h$ on the two sides we get $hg =gh$. But the only element in $S$ commuting with $g$ is $g$ itself, from which $g=h$. This is a contradiction since $gh=e$ is not in $S$. This holds if the group has cardinality at least 4.

Your construction in paragraph 2 gives all examples!

Now the conjugacy action $G$ on $S$ gives an injective map $i:G\to S_{|G|/2}$.

I follow you up to here but here I think you've made a small extra assumption here. Namely, why is this map injective? You need to know that $S$ contains at least two elements $s_1, s_2$ to conclude that $C_G(s_1) \cap C_G(s_2) = \{ e \}$ so that the action of $G$ by conjugation on $S$ has trivial kernel. But, to be pedantic, this condition doesn't hold if $|G| = 2$.
Fortunately that case is contained in your construction in the second paragraph. So, assuming now that $|G| > 2$, your observation about fixed points implies that the action of $G$ on $S$ makes $G$ a Frobenius group; if $s \in S$ is any element then $C_2 = \{ e, s \}$ is a Frobenius complement, and $G \setminus S$ is its Frobenius kernel, which by Frobenius' theorem is a normal subgroup $K$ (it's not at all obvious a priori that $K$ is closed under multiplication), which as you've shown has odd order. From here it follows that $G$ is a semidirect product
$$G \cong K \rtimes C_2$$
where $K$ has odd order and $s \in C_2$ acts via an automorphism $\varphi : K \to K$ of order $2$ which fixes only the identity. Conversely, with these hypotheses the action of $K$ on $s$ by conjugation has trivial stabilizer and so must produce all of $G \setminus K$, so $G$ has a conjugacy class of size $\frac{|G|}{2}$.
So the remaining problem is to classify pairs $(K, \varphi)$ of a finite group of odd order and an automorphism $\varphi$ as above. Wikipedia claims that a Frobenius group whose Frobenius complement has even order (which is the case here) must have the property that the Frobenius kernel $K$ is abelian; that ought to have a direct proof in this special case but I'm afraid I don't see it. Assuming that:

Proposition: Suppose $K$ is a finite abelian group of odd order and $\varphi : K \to K$ is an automorphism of order $2$ with no non-trivial fixed points. Then $\varphi(k) = -k$.

Proof. Since $K$ has odd order, multiplication by $2$ is invertible, so we can divide by $2$. This lets us write every $k \in K$ as a sum
$$k = \frac{k + \varphi(k)}{2} + \frac{k - \varphi(k)}{2}$$
of an element fixed by $\varphi$ and an element negated by $\varphi$; this expresses $K$ as a direct sum $K \cong K_1 \oplus K_{-1}$ of the eigenspaces of $\varphi$ (note that we don't need to assume that $K$ is a vector space over a finite field!). Since $\varphi$ has no nontrivial fixed points, $K_1 = \{ e \}$ is trivial, so $K = K_{-1}$ as desired. $\Box$

Without assuming $K$ is abelian, the proof involves a little trick: define  $f: K\to K$ given by $f(k)=k^{-1}\varphi(k)$, check that it's injective, so it's surjective by finiteness. One can then deduce that $\varphi$ is inversion so $K$ is abelian. See https://linearalgebras.com/solution-abstract-algebra-exercise-1-6-23.html for example

You don't need Frobenius's theorem to find $K$. In the regular representation, an element of order $2$ in $G$ is a product of $|G|/2$ transpositions, hence lies outside $A_{|G|}$. Intersection with the alternating subgroup then gives a normal subgroup of index $2$.
